# Jar files not created by maven

Tags: maven

I am trying to get the jar file with the help of mavn by running the command mvn -f /spark-monitoring-main/src/pom.xml install -P scala-2.12_spark-3.1.2 -D skipTests -e

But I am getting errors.

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.4.2:compile (default) on project spark-listeners: wrap: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.4.2:compile (default) on project spark-listeners: wrap: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specifie

Answer (score 0):

You only have a Java Runtime.  You need a full Java Development Kit which includes the Java compiler `javac`.

Several are available for easy usage, including one from Microsoft for Windows.  Choose one that fits your operating system, hardware platform (32/64 bits) and general needs and try again.